# check how many time the function execute in x seconds? c#

Tags: c#

i want to check how many time my function executed in x seconds like 3 seconds i have seen 1 stack example that is similar but  not full fill my prob..

actually i am working on AUTOMATION UI and my event excuted many time so i have a solution that i am passing name of dialogue to my function and need to check weather the same name passes to function when the same function executed in next 3-4 sec is same if yes i will return my event handlers so here is my code to event automation ui

```
Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
    WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
    AutomationElement.RootElement,
    System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Subtree,
    (sender, e) =>
    {
        string  dialogueName = sd.Current.Name;
        if (element.Current.LocalizedControlType == "Dialog")
        {
            starttimer(dialogueName );//how to get returned value there
        }
    }
});
```

fucntion code

```
public static nameRecent;
public bool checkerfunctionOFname(string name )
{
    if (nameRecent==name)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

**Reason** why i am need timer 3-4 sec is that suppose user open a save as dialogue but closes then after 10 ec again open so this match the previous open name that is static but when ever he opens the save as dialogue then the same repeats it self with same name in 3 sec so if function again execute is 3 sec it return false etc

solution to code but arrange it when function return false how can i get it in event handler or how i stop it main function to return

```
     public static string  globalfucntiontime;
    public static string globalfucntionname;
    int _counter = 0;
    Timer timer;
  public void  starttimer(string name){

  _counter = 0;
  timer = new Timer();
  timer.Interval = 1000;
  timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        TimerEventProcessor(name);   //how to get its returned value
    globalfucntiontime = _counter.ToString();
    timer.Start();


 }

 private bool  TimerEventProcessor(string name)
   {
  globalfucntionname = name; 
  if (_counter <= 3 && name == globalfucntionname)
  {

      return false;
  }
  else if (name !=  globalfucntionname)
  {


  }
   globalfucntiontime = _counter.ToString();
   _counter += 1;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: what about a timer run in a seperate thread that constantly prints a variable that is modified by your function? get the timer to trigger reporting every x seconds.

Comment: @Sinatr This is not about the execution time of a method.

Comment: @Sinatr This question is about: How to check if a method was already called during the last n seconds

Comment: @SirRufo, agree. Didn't understood the problem at first.

Comment: I'd avoid *pushing* user like this (opening dialogs without him being involved). What if user is already doing something (e.g. editing text somewhere) and then your dialog pops up in the middle of typing? Instead you can show him this option to open dialog somewhere (e.g. as a button). Then user is free to click it when he wants and you can show this button again and again without consequences. Otherwise (if you insists to keep it as it is) you have to synchronize access to method (see. `Monitor.TryEnter/Monitor.Exit` coupled with `try/finally`).

Comment: the approach is not seem gud but have solution runing a counter then checking its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the name and the calling timstamp into a dictionary. Now you can ask that dictionary, if that name was called during the last n seconds.

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string,int> lastcalled = new Dictionary<string,int>();

    public void RegisterCallOf( string name )
    { 
        int now = Environment.TickCount;
        if ( lastcalled.ContainsKey( name ) )
            lastcalled[name] = now;
        else
            lastcalled.Add( name, now );
    }

    public bool WasCalledDuringLast( string name, int milliseconds )
    {
        int now = Environment.TickCount;
        if ( lastcalled.ContainsKey( name ) )
          return now - lastcalled[name] <= milliseconds;
        return false; 
    }
}
```

## Example for using

```
// check if that "bar" was already called within the last 3000ms
if ( !foo.WasCalledDuringLast( "bar", 3000 ) )
{
    // it was not, so now we register this call
    foo.RegisterCallOf( "bar" );
    // and now call that bar method
}
```

## Update

For an easier use you can extend that class with

```
public void ExecuteIfWasNotCalledDuringLast( string name, int milliseconds, Action action )
{
    if ( !WasCalledDuringLast( name, milliseconds ) )
    {
        RegisterCallOf( name );
        action();
    }
}
```

and you will use that method

```
foo.ExecuteIfWasNotCalledDuringLast( "bar", 3000, barAction );
```

Comment: time in mili you mean 1000 = 1 sec or should i check against 1 , 2

Comment: i am passing 5000 fucntion repeating but alwaying giving false

Comment: SOLUTION ACCEPTABLE BUT LITTLE MODIFY OR CHECK PLEASE

Comment: here comes a problem , it must enter the value and gives the between time like in 5000ms this exists

Comment: @zulqarnainkhalil please check the edit ... and please do not shout (using capitalized letters is like shouting)

Comment: this is ok but dictionary can create same key prob ..if bar entered as key can baar entered again as key so ans is no so Now as key check tell me so mark it ok

Comment: So you want to suppress only equal calls within a certain timespan? Calling bar, bar, foo within 2 seconds will call bar once and foo once. Calling bar, foo, bar within 2 seconds will call bar, foo and bar again? If that is what you want we do not need that dictionary at all, only two fields for the name and the timestamp

Comment: sir i checked that dictionary empties it self automatically i checked value with debugging it shows count = 0 many time even after adding key value then again become zero automatically using same code

Comment: remember i am adding same key in 3 sec like "bar" so function to add calls it self 3 times in 3 ec

Comment: Seems you create always a new instance of that "foo" class?

Comment: no i added fucntions in my own class directly using functions

Comment: Well I can only reproduce this if I create a new instance of that Foo class. Of course each instance will start with an empty directory.

Comment: LAST thing sir can you please tell me why automation function is slow or does not work for some events like open dialogue http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1114347/Automation-event-calls-multiple-time-but-for-open

Comment: What do you mean by "i put whole class"?

Comment: mean i refered to the class previoues i was using the code in my event class that each time initiate on event arise so createing problem now i turn Foo static and then refred function of foo as you did so as it is static its only 1 instance been called , but thanx can you please check my last 2 comments i have given link i badly need help there too thankyou

Comment: the issue multiple time calling resolved their by your help at above link question but the other issue why not calling open and save dialogue open or some time stops is not answered there

Comment: Sorry, but I am not an Automation guru :o) You should ask a new question for that topic here on SO